# Do more creative people have more unusual dreams?

Tags: dreams, creativity

Title says it all: Do more creative people have more unusual dreams?

Comment: How are you quantifying creativity and how are you making sure a person is reliably reporting a dream and not just fabricating the interesting parts?

Comment: @Seanny123 Good question. I was definitely hoping for an analysis that was more qualitative than quantitative. I would assume any studies on the contents of dreams would necessarily depend on participants being honest and having good memories of their dreams. I would assume both of which would have high levels of error. So I'm not really hoping for a definitive answer. I'm more hoping for possible evidence or reasoning supporting one way or the other.

Comment: I've asked a similar question, although mine is more about quantity than quality: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8668/do-creative-people-dream-more-and-or-differently-than-average-or-analytical-peop

Comment: I would like to know of the dreams of Van Gogh as well if they close i will vote to reopen